# React: why setState cause unmount a component inside a stateless component?

Tags: reactjs

Please see this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjowbq?editors=0011 You can drag the input box to change the value.

```
  render()
  {
      var self = this;
      var onChangeValue = (val)=>{
          value = val;//value is a global variable.
          self.setState({});
      };
      var Box = ()=>{
           return <NumberBox step = {1} value={value} onChangeValue={onChangeValue}/>
      };

    return <div>
        <Box/>
        <NumberBox step = {1} value={value} onChangeValue={onChangeValue}/>
    </div>;
  }
```

See the code in `class Application`, the first `NumberBox` is inside a stateless component `Box`. If you drag it, it will be unmount.

But the second one work proporly. The only difference is whether or not the `NumberBox` is in a stateless component.

Comment: Post relevant code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stateless component should be in out side of the class Component, So it can receive the props.
Check this code ,

```
const Box = ({ value, onChangeValue}) => 
       <NumberBox 
          step = {1} 
          value={value} 
          onChangeValue={onChangeValue}
        />
```

https://codepen.io/gopinathkaliappan/pen/Peboxe

Comment: So what is my mistake. Can you give me some official document about this? As I guess, when I change the `Application` state, it find I didnt change the `Box` states nor props. So it will not update the `Box` and `NumberBox` inside `Box`. But why unmount?

Comment: What is your expected output, so we can help you out

Comment: The `NumberBox` can be dragged to change value. But if I call `setState` to force `NumberBox` update it's value, it will unmount and stop the draging. Of cause I can use your solution to solve the problem. But I want to know why to avoid making mistake in the future.

Comment: You are returning a component in render method (get some idea about Component Life cycle), make sure that your render method contains only dom's (for best Practice)

Comment: Ok. I know why. It is not because you add props to `Box`, but the `Box` is a const. When `Box` is inside the render function, everytime it render, react will think `Box` is different(another?) component class, so it will unmout it. I know it. Thank you.